# USB 3 adapter for a dell 2850 with PCI (or PCIX) ports?

Tags: pci, usb-3, expansion-cards

Does anyone know if there is a plain PCI (or PCIX) USB 3 adapter? I understand the bandwidth of PCI < USB3, but it still beats the heck out of USB 2.  I have some older dell 2850s that do not have the PCI E ports that most USB 3 adapters require.  I'd really like to get usb3 in those servers.  I searched the internet but didn't see any. The local computer store said they only had pcie adapters. Do these exist?

Comment: Would eSATA give you the performance you need in teh older server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware, so far, of any USB 3 implementation on PCI/PCI-X bus. The currently used NEC chip that implement USB 3.0 protocol has PCI-Express controllers built into the chip, integrated. Thus it is highly unlikely that USB3 would appear in PCI/PCI-X settings.

For the matter, would a PCI eSATA adapter help?